# How to convert currency values in DataFrame column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got a dataframe which has columns -

```
Product    Price in AUD    Price in BTC    Price in USD        Date
  A           1450.22         0.120             NaN         2019-08-15
  B             NaN           NaN               550         2019-09-12
  C             NaN           0.18             1500         2019-09-02
  D             NaN           NaN              1244         2019-09-10
```

I need to convert all alternate prices (Price in Bitcoin and Price in US Dollar) to `Price in AUD` where the value of `Price in AUD` is null. If both alternate prices are given (eg. C), I want to use `Price in BTC` to convert to AUD, else whichever is available.

How can I do this? Is there an API or Python library that I can use for this, since the prices of Bitcoin and USD keep fluctuating everyday? I would like to use the `Date` column to get the exact conversion value in AUD on that date. Has anyone done something similar and can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [forex-python](https://pypi.org/project/forex-python/) package for that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from forex_python.bitcoin import BtcConverter

data =  [('A',           1450.22  ,       0.120   , None            ,      '2019-08-15')
     ,('B',       None      ,  None    ,          550   ,      '2019-09-12')
      ,('C',       None      ,      0.18    ,         1500   ,      '2019-09-02')
      ,('D',       None      ,  None    ,         1244   ,      '2019-09-10')]
colNames = ['Product',    'Price in AUD',    'Price in BTC',    'Price in USD',        'Date']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=colNames)

c = CurrencyRates()
b = BtcConverter()

def convertBtcToAUD(row):        
    if pd.isna(row['Price in AUD']):
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d')

        aud = b.convert_btc_to_cur_on(row['Price in BTC'], 'AUD', date )
    else:
        aud = row['Price in AUD']

    return aud

def convertUSDToAUD(row):        
    if pd.isna(row['Price in AUD']):
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d')

        aud = c.convert('USD', 'AUD', row['Price in USD'], date )
    else:
        aud = row['Price in AUD']

    return aud

df['Price in AUD'] = df.apply(convertBtcToAUD, axis=1)
df['Price in AUD'] = df.apply(convertUSDToAUD, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Product  Price in AUD  Price in BTC  Price in USD        Date
0       A   1450.220000          0.12           NaN  2019-08-15
1       B    799.840372           NaN         550.0  2019-09-12
2       C   2783.197980          0.18        1500.0  2019-09-02
3       D   1814.504710           NaN        1244.0  2019-09-10
```

P.S.: Please keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a code writting service. I just provided an answer because I was interested in the problem.

Comment: Sorry I should have made the question more specific for where I was gettting stuck, but was trying to save some time on framing it...

Comment: Trying to run your solution, it runs fine for BTC to AUD, but gives me a `DecimalFloatMismatchError('convert  requires amount parameter is of type Decimal when force _decimal=True', 'occurred at index 6')` in the USD to AUD function... any help?

Comment: What is the value of `row['Price in USD']` when the error occurs?

Comment: Oh nevermind sorry! I had a `$` in that particular row.. my bad!

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to check if `row['Price in USD']` or `row['Price in BTC']` is a float before calling the API.